# Are there any ldap proxy servers that can supplement the results from the main ldap server?

Tags: active-directory, proxy, ldap, openldap

We have a central ldap server that authenticates and provides authorization information about users in our institution. I am looking for a LDAP Proxy that supplement the central LDAP server to support specific needs in our department.

For example, Say, I request the central LDAP server for information about a user and get:

```
centralSchemaFieldX
centralSchemaFieldY
centralSchemaFieldZ
```

I would like to add more fields to the results so that the requested client get the result as:

```
centralSchemaFieldX
centralSchemaFieldY
centralSchemaFieldZ
myDeptScemaFieldX
myDeptScemaFieldY
myDeptScemaFieldZ
```

Is there product available that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Meta backend for OpenLDAP to create a unified view of two directories. [This article](http://blog.oddbit.com/2010/02/16/merging-directories-with-openldap-meta/) by user @larsks details the configuration.

Comment: As usual, please avoid link-only answers to prevent link rot. Either write the essential parts into your answer or post the link as a comment.

Comment: @SvW I disagree. The OP didn't ask for a configuration, he asked for a product, and this answer provides one. The link to a configuration article is a bonus.